# Checkout workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have some VBA i'm trying to get to check out a workbook before making changes.  The VBA code sits in its own work book, and is activated by a user opening the other work book and selecting a button which executes code to modify the workbook.  At the beginning I want to check if the work book is checked out.  The issue I am getting is Workbooks.CanCheckOut(ActiveWorkbook.FullName) always returns false, even if the work book is not checked out.

```
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(ActiveWorkbook.FullName) = True Then
    Workbooks.CheckOut (ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
    MsgBox "This workbook has been checked out"
    Process = True
ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.CanCheckIn = False Then 'if not checked out
    Process = False
    MsgBox ("The Document may not be checked out, Import Process is ending.")
Else
    Process = True
End If 'If CanCheckin = False
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure which book has the code and which has been opened, but I would think if you are checking "ActiveWorkbook", that implies that it is open -- possibly returning the false value.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn is on the right track but I will add that what's happening is the way you are passing the value is null so you are getting a break in your check. Can you upload the workbook with the code and a sample workbook that would be normally checked and I try to fix the logic for you hands on.

Answer (score 5):

I've found through trial and error that `Workbooks.CanCheckOut (Filename:= FullName)` where FullName is the URL for the SharePoint file **only works for files that are not open in the current instance of Excel.**

The method will always return `False` if you have the file open in the current instance of Excel which is obviously the case here.

`Workbooks.CheckOut (ActiveWorkbook.FullName)` opens the file, checks it out and then inexplicably, closes the file. So opening and checking out a SharePoint file becomes a 3 step process.

```
Sub CheckOutAndOpen()
Dim TestFile As String

    TestFile = "http://spserver/document/Test.xlsb"
    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(TestFile) = True Then
        Workbooks.CheckOut(TestFile)
        Workbooks.Open (TestFile)
    Else
        MsgBox TestFile & " can't be checked out at this time.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

This is all a bit counter intuitive because when working manually with SharePoint files you have to open them to see if they can be checked out and then perform the check-out operation.

Neither MSDN or Excel VBA help mention that the `Workbooks.CanCheckOut (Filename:= FullName)` method always returns False if you have the file open in the current instance of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CheckOutAndOpenFromSharePoint()
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName as string

FilePath = "http://Sharepoint site/Folder Name On SharePoint Site/"
FileName = "Testing.xlsx"
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(FilePath & FileName) = True Then
    Workbooks.CheckOut "http://Sharepoint%20site/Folder%20Name%20On%20SharePoint%Site/Testing.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath & FileName
Else
    MsgBox FileName & " can't be checked out at this time.", vbInformation
End If
End Sub
```