# How exactly does checking in/checking out a SharePoint/OneDrive document work in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, onedrive

My overall goal is for one Excel document, where this code resides, to open a separate Excel document stored in SharePoint/OneDrive, write some data to it, then close it. The document with the code is intended to be used by me and some of my coworkers, and we all write to the same secondary I have these two functions that open and close a workbook, respectively.

Here's the code:

```vb
Function open_wb() As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb_name As String
    wb_name = "https://redacted/path/to/file.xlsb"

    Dim checked_out As Boolean
    checked_out = False
    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(wb_name) Then
        Call Workbooks.CheckOut(wb_name)
        checked_out = True
        Set open_wb = Workbooks.Open(wb_name)
    End If
    
    If Not checked_out Then
        Set open_wb = Nothing
    End If
End Function

Function close_wb(ByRef wb As Workbook)
    If wb.CanCheckIn Then
        wb.CheckIn SaveChanges:=True, Comments:="abc"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Set wb = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to check in"
    End If
End Function
```

Now the problems I've having with this. Firstly, it seems to work fine for my coworker, but when I try to use it, the written to file can't be checked out. Unless I have it open in Excel. This flies in the face [of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230441/) which says the file should not be open.

Another concern I have: if somehow the file is checked out and not checked back in, does it necessarily have to be manually checked in (or the checkout discarded)?

It seems these `CanCheckOut` and `CanCheckIn` functions provide little recourse if they return false. If I can't check out the file, what options do I have to fix that? It also concerns me that, in my testing, I've run into situations where `CanCheckOut` returned true and then I received an error from `Workbooks.CheckOut`. In what circumstances do these functions fail, and how do I react to the failure?

Comment: Why the need to check the file out? You could just make your edits without checking the file out. Excel has  been supporting simultaneous multi-user access for SharePoint files for quite a while now, which reduces the need to check files out..

Comment: @teylyn I tried that initially. In my testing, I found that data written to the second file was not always saved, particularly when two users write to the file with a certain timeframe. I was hoping checking out the file would prevent that.